# How to pass the function result according to the parameter to props

Tags: reactjs

My program has a page that repeat the component called CanvasCard 9 times.
That your structure

```
                      <Row className='card-columns'>
                      <CanvasCard title='Parceiros Chave' cardID='1' color='blue-violet'
                        description={this.state.description}
                        list={this.state.list}
                      />                      
                      <Row style={{ margin: '0px' }}>
                        <CanvasCard title='Atividades Chave' cardID='2' class='card-height' color='green'
                          description={this.state.description}
                          list={this.state.list}
                        />
                        <CanvasCard title='Recursos Chave' cardID='3' class='card-height' color='orange'
                          description={this.state.description}
                          list={this.state.list}
                        />
                      </Row> ....
```

`this.state.list` contains an array with all cards data, for example:

```
   {_id: "5d78d065ad06c71d4714156c", name: "Canvas", __v: 0, cards: Array(11), createdAt: "2019-09-11T10:45:57.984Z"}
    cards: Array(11)
    0: {description: "parceiro 01", cardID: "1", _id: "5d7a209fad06c71d47141596", createdAt: "2019-09-12T10:40:31.323Z"}
1: {description: "parceiro 02", cardID: "1", _id: "5d7a3e61ad06c71d4714159e", createdAt: "2019-09-12T12:47:29.532Z"}
2: {description: "parc3", cardID: "1", _id: "5d7a4bcb3b441c223ac74e01", createdAt: "2019-09-12T13:44:43.548Z"}
3: {description: "atividade 00", cardID: "2", _id: "5d7a790a3b441c223ac74e04", createdAt: "2019-09-12T16:57:46.924Z"}
4: {description: "recurso 01", cardID: "3", _id: "5d7a795f3b441c223ac74e05", createdAt: "2019-09-12T16:59:11.026Z"}
5: {description: "Proposta 01", cardID: "4", _id: "5d7a797b3b441c223ac74e06", createdAt: "2019-09-12T16:59:39.202Z"}
6: {description: "Relação 01", cardID: "5", _id: "5d7a79b03b441c223ac74e08", createdAt: "2019-09-12T17:00:32.417Z"}
7: {description: "Canais 01", cardID: "6", _id: "5d7a79b63b441c223ac74e09", createdAt: "2019-09-12T17:00:38.256Z"}
8: {description: "Canais 02", cardID: "6", _id: "5d7a79b93b441c223ac74e0a", createdAt: "2019-09-12T17:00:41.080Z"}
9: {description: "Segmentos 01", cardID: "7", _id: "5d7a79bc3b441c223ac74e0b", createdAt: "2019-09-12T17:00:44.672Z"}
10: {description: "Esttrutura de Custos 01", cardID: "8", _id: "5d7a79c33b441c223ac74e0c", createdAt: "2019-09-12T17:00:51.152Z"}
11: {description: "Fontes de Renda 01", cardID: "9", _id: "5d7a79c73b441c223ac74e0d", createdAt: "2019-09-12T17:00:55.945Z"}
```

I'm calling this array 9 times (one per CanvasCard component).

The canvasCard component receive this array and check which are the objects with your respective ID.
For example, the first canvasCard of the example is this:

```
 <CanvasCard title='Parceiros Chave' cardID='1' color='blue-violet'
                            description={this.state.description}
                            list={this.state.list}
                          />
```

This canvasCard contains the `cardID=1`, so your data according to the `this.state.list` array is those:

```
0: {description: "parceiro 01", cardID: "1"}
1: {description: "parceiro 02", cardID: "1"}
2: {description: "parc3", cardID: "1"}
```

Instead of pass all the array using `this.state.list` in each CanvasCard component, how can I pass only an array with their respective objects (according to the cardID)?

I tried do something like this, but it does not works:

```
                       canvasCardData = id => {        
                         return this.state.list[0].cards.filter(x => x.cardID == id)    
                       }

                       <CanvasCard title='Parceiros Chave' cardID='1' color='blue-violet'
                        description={this.state.description}
                        list={() => canvasCardData(1)}
                      />                                               
                       <CanvasCard title='Atividades Chave' cardID='2' class='card-height' color='green'
                         description={this.state.description}
                         list={() => canvasCardData(2)}
                       />
                       <CanvasCard title='Recursos Chave' cardID='3' class='card-height' color='orange'
                         description={this.state.description}
                         list={() => canvasCardData(3)}
                       />
```

Comment: do you mean you want to go over the array of card and generate the card component dynamically with their respective properties.. if so have you tried `map` over it ??

Comment: @Panther I tried it, my problem is when i do it ` list={() => canvasCardData(cardID)}

Comment: can you show your `cards` data ?? The shown cards data does not have an `_id` property

Comment: @Panther I updated the questions. There is an `_id`, I removed it to simplify my question.

Comment: @Panther I updated the `canvasCardData` function

Comment: with tis updated code, looks like you are passing `canvasCardData(3)` as a number while `canvasCardData('3')` would work

Comment: It doesnt make difference because I'm not using this operator:`===`

Comment: you are passing a function to `list`, i hope you are calling it inside. if not just send `list={canvasCardData('3')}

Comment: @Panther tku, that's solved my problem. I did it I `this.canvasCardData(3)`

Answer (score 1):

you pass a number instead of string. You need to make id types consistence.

Comment: It doesnt make difference because I'm not using this operator: `===`

Comment: You can build a new array which include your relative data, and then use map only https://jsfiddle.net/L6b4vwya/

Answer (score 0):

You must use `map` for render each component.

You can look at the [link](https://jsfiddle.net/jr4pk5hf/2/)